# Undesired behaviour within systeme

Tags: equations, symbols, systeme

When I try to write a sum over some index in systeme* within an align environment, the sum is not displayed in the usual way, with the index displayed under the summation symbol, but instead on the lower right as if in inline math mode. Any workarounds?

```
\begin{align}
    \systeme*{\sum_{i \in I_1} f_i  = C}
\end{align}
```

Comment: How about your show your code so we can visualize what you're talking about? Can you do that?

Comment: You can use `\displaystyle\sum` instead of `\sum`.  Also, the behavior occurs even in `\[...\]`...it is not peculiar to `align`.

Comment: Please post a complete example rather than a mere snippet of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `\systeme` for *explicit* linear systems, when you want to align the variables. In your case there's nothing to align (and just one formula), so you want

```
\begin{equation}
\biggl\{\,\sum_{i\in I_1} f_i = C
\end{equation}
```

If you have more than one summation, you can use an inner `aligned`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

If you have just one equation to display
\begin{equation}
\biggl\{\,\sum_{i\in I_1} f_i = C
\end{equation}
but if you have more than one, you can do
\begin{equation}
\left\{
  \begin{aligned}
  \sum_{i\in I_1} f_i &= C_1 \\
  \sum_{i\in I_2} f_i &= C_2 \\
  \vdots\quad \\
  \sum_{i\in I_n} f_i &= C_n
  \end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the first case, the alternative of `\Biggl\{` (or `\left\{` with a matching `\right.` at the end) is not as attractive:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I take it that you wish to insert a tall opening curly brace to the left of the equation, and also that the equation should be typset ins display-style math mode.

If this interpretation is correct, employing the `systeme` package to achieve your formatting objective is akin to trying to smash a fly with a sledgehammer. You might succeed, but why exert so much effort? Don't do it. Instead, just use `\left\{` and `\right.` directives.

And, since there's just one equation to typeset, there's no need to the `align` machinery. Instead, use a basic `equation` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \left\{ \,
    \sum_{i \in I_1} f_i  = C
    \right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```